# Im trying to implement a calendar to my ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, ionic3

Im trying to implement a calendar to my ionic 3 project but I keep getting this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-calendar'.
```

Here is my app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { CalendarModule } from "ion2-calendar";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
     MyApp,
     ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
HttpModule,
CalendarModule
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
],
 providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my html

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
(onChange)="onChange($event)"
[type]="type"
[format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
</ion-calendar>
```

And this is my ts for the html page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-calendar',
templateUrl: 'calendar.html', 
  })

export class CalendarPage {
 date: string;
 type: 'string'; // 'string' | 'js-date' | 'moment' | 'time' | 'object'

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

onChange($event) {
 console.log($event);
 }
ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad CalendarPage');
 }

 }
```

Any idea? I have already installed `npm install ion2-calendar moment --save`
All the help is aprecciated 
Someone told me it might be the lazy loading from ionic 3

Comment: Which calendar module are you using? URL?

Comment: Im using this one https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import` `CalendarComponentOptions` class as shown below into your page.

*calendar.ts*

```
import { CalendarComponentOptions } from 'ion2-calendar'
```

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work, it still says the same, I put the calendar in a blank project and it worked but when I try to put it in another project it doesnt work

Comment: You need to share the project url.

Comment: OK, you didn't configure it properly. Is this a test project? Can you share it through public git repo? Here is an article about stackblitz: https://medium.com/@ericsimons/stackblitz-online-vs-code-ide-for-angular-react-7d09348497f4

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yenapaxmf865bbb/example.zip?dl=0 I put in this dropbox, Im not very familiar with git... sorry